# C++ Separate Function File

Tags: c++, function, header, iostream

i'm trying to write my c++ program in different files, but I can't seem to get it to work. can someone help me?

separate.cpp

```
#include "separate.h"
#include <iostream>

void Separate() {

cout << "text";

}
```

separate.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class OneLine {

    Separate();

private:
    string vari;

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "separate.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    Separate s;
    s();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did this work in a single file?? You are declaring a function `Separate` of a class `OneLine`, but then try to create a `Separate` object.

Comment: Advice: Include approved headers first:
#include <iostream>
than #include "separate.h"

Comment: You should avoid `using namespace std`, specially in headers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @DieterLücking: Why is `iostream` "approved"? If you include it first you'll never know if the header file (e.g. `separate.h`) is self-sufficient and doesn't rely on undeclared functions or types. Always include e.g. `separate.h` first.

Comment: Because your headers might introduce new overloads or macros which mess up the std headers.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier assume your header (included before) has just '{' in it - than an #include <iostream> in g++ will result in "/usr/include/c++/4.7/exception:37:37: error: expected declaration before end of line"

Comment: @DieterLücking: That example is badly broken (or very special needs code) no matter where you include it and it is definitely an example of a header file which isn't selfy-sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two basic errors:

In `separate.cpp`, you need

```
void OneLine::Separate() { /*...*/ }
```

and in `main.cpp` you want to create an object of your type and call the defined method on it like this:

```
OneLine ol;
ol.Separate();
```

For this, you need to make the method `public`, change `separate.h`:

```
class OneLine {

public:
    Separate();

//...
};
```

You want to change a few more things as well which are not needed for this simple example but they will become necessary in the long run:

- You want include guards, google for "include guard"
- You don't want `using namespace std;` - get rid of it and add `std::` where necessary

Comment: @Useless Yes, I missed that one and fixed the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your implementation define the function as:

```
void OneLine::Separate() {
  ...
```

In your main, you need to instantiate a OneLine object and call Separate on that, i.e.:

```
OneLine o;
o.Separate();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your main file you need to reference `"separate.h"` rather than `"separate.cpp"`

In `seperate.cpp` the class method needs to be prefixed with the class name:

```
void Oneline::Separate()
```

Also you should be creating an object of type `OneLine` rather than of type `Seperate`.

So:

```
Oneline one;
one.Seperate();
```